# how to call soap server using nusoap

Tags: php, soap

i need to call a soap server, they provide request format like this (please see this page https://book.mylimobiz.com/api/ApiService.asmx?op=Test)

```
POST /api/ApiService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: book.mylimobiz.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "https://book.mylimobiz.com/api/Test"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Test xmlns="https://book.mylimobiz.com/api">
      <apiId>string</apiId>
      <apiKey>string</apiKey>
    </Test>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am using php nusoap to send request, and here is ho i am trying

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');

$serverPath = "https://book.mylimobiz.com/api/ApiService.asmx";
$param = array("apiId"=>"someapi","apiKey"=>"somekYE");
$client = new SoapClient($serverPath);

    $tt = $client->call("Test",$param,"https://book.mylimobiz.com/api","https://book.mylimobiz.com/api/Test");
```

which is not working
can some one guide me how to request using nusoap or some thing else.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
 $client = new SoapClient('https://book.mylimobiz.com/api/ApiService.asmx?WSDL');
 $params = array();
 $params["apiId"] = apiId;
 $params["apiKey"] = apiKey;
 $result = $client->Test($params);
```